# TS2305: Module "typescript" has no exported member 'Iterator'

Tags: typescript

I recently updated to typescript v5 and am now getting the following typescript compiler error:

`TS2305: Module '"typescript"' has no exported member 'Iterator'.`

Which is referencing this line within my source code:

`import { Iterator } from 'typescript';`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed this by removing the

`import { Iterator } from 'typescript';`

As per the [typescript breaking changes doc](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/API-Breaking-Changes#typescript-50)

> ts.Map, ts.Set, ts.ESMap, ts.Iterator, and associated types have been removed. The native Map, Set, Iterator and associated types should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript error you're encountering (TS2305: Module '"typescript"' has no exported member 'Iterator') is caused by the fact that the Iterator interface has been removed in TypeScript 4.3 and later versions. Therefore, you won't find the Iterator export in the typescript module anymore.

To resolve this error, you should remove the import { Iterator } from 'typescript'; line from your source code because it's no longer necessary or valid.

If you were using the Iterator type for specific purposes in your code, you'll need to find an alternative approach or utilize other TypeScript types/interfaces that suit your needs. The removal of the Iterator type is part of the TypeScript language changes, and it's important to update your code accordingly.

Removing the import statement should resolve the TypeScript compiler error related to the missing Iterator export.